# Safari 11 Bug Fieldset-Legend with Overflow Hidden and Click

Tags: html, css, safari, legend, fieldset

Since Safari 11 for Mac checkboxes (and links/other click-events) are inaccessible when placed in a `<legend>`, does anyone know of a workaround? JS fiddle contains a demo, neither the checkbox can be checked, nor the click-event fires. Both work in Safari 10.2, but not in Safari 11. Also when I set the legend to `position: relative` the legend disappears. Setting the fieldset from `overflow: hidden` to  `overflow: visible` seems to work, but I'd like to keep it hidden, as this could have other consequences in other browsers. Thanks!

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/xyb/pen/KXMyMK)

Comment: We experience this problem as well, and removing `overflow: hidden` solves the immediate issue in our case. With a bit of luck, this is a bug in Safari which will be fixed.

Comment: I sent a bug report to Apple as well. Not holding my breath, but with a bit of luck, they'll release a fix.

Comment: I ended up using JS/jQuery (was included already in my project). If you set the `fieldset` to `position: relative`, then (and only then) the `legend` click event is fired. So now on click I set the checkbox's `pointer-events` to `none` and toggle the checkbox. Demo https://codepen.io/xyb/pen/zEKdqP. Hella ugly, but it works and can be applied to only Safari 11 (via JS)

Comment: "With a bit of luck, this is a bug in Safari which will be fixed" -> We either didn't have luck, or isn't recognized as a bug. It's still an issue